# htaccess subdirectory + 301 on www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to do 2 things with htaccess but I can't figure out how to do it.
Let's say my domain is domain.com
First, I'd like to force www. in the url with a 301 redirect.

Another thing, my website is not hosted in the root directory but in /laravel/public/

So I'd like to set this subdirectory as root, and remove it from the URL if someone try www.domain.com/laravel/public/ => www.domain.com

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can't change the document root to point to your public folder, you can try adding these rules to **document root** (not your public folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+lavarel/public/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravel/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first rule is working just fine.

Bur for the second one, if I try www.domain.com/laravel/public/* or domain.com/laravel/public/*, the subdirectories part (/laravel/public/) is not hidden from the url.

Comment: @rombat In order to do that, you need a second redirect.

Comment: Ok thanks. What would it look like? (I seriously lack knowledge about use of htaccess).

Comment: It's still not working. /laravel/public/ is still in the url, with or without www

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have your own `.htaccess` file in the root of your domain, along with another in the `laravel/public` directory (there already is one there, but you need to modify it.

Below are the two files in full as I have them on my testing server.

**`/.htaccess`**

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite requests to the laravel/public index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel/public/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravel/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**`/laravel/public/.htaccess`**

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Force www. (also strips laravel/public)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Strip laravel/public, prevent loops
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/laravel/public(/.+)/? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```